# Where and how to publish new work?

Tags: publishing, science-fiction, publisher

I have made several stories, not short, but not long. They might make a small book.

But I'm new and don't know anything,

Where should I publish it, I mean, safely, as they could rip off the idea or just throw the work away. Any advice will be appreciated too.

Comment: [Amazon CreateSpace](https://www.createspace.com/)?

Comment: An unrelated word of advice: find an editor to look over your work before you publish.

Answer (score 6):

You can publish them yourself. If you do that, you retain *all* of the rights to the stories and the book. That way, nobody can get the rights to the book and throw them away.

To publish an ebook, you can make an epub file and distribute it through Kindle, Apple iBooks, Kobo, Nook, Smashwords, and other places. They won't steal it. They want to sell it for you, so they can take their 30%.

To publish a paperback, you can design the cover and the interior, make PDFs of those, and use CreateSpace (print-on-demand) to print and ship it. CreateSpace sells through their own online store, and through Amazon. Depending on how you price the book, they can also distribute it more widely for you (so that it could end up in brick-and-mortar stores).

I do all of the above. There are likely many other options, especially for ebooks.

Comment: There are other on-demand publishers besides CreateSpace, so they're not your only option in that direction. I have one (paper) book published with Lulu and another with CreateSpace. Both of these are also available as ebooks. There are a bunch of POD publishers out there. If you want or are willing to do pretty much all the work yourself, I think CreateSpace and Lulu are the clear choices. If you want to just write the text and let someone else handle the technical parts, there are a number of other publishers, but they are, of course, going to charge for their services.

Comment: I think you can also hire out the services. Editing. Book cover design. Interior design. Ebook conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Great question! There are a couple things you could do.

1. Look at magazines that would publish your works. This would be my first recommendation. If you've never published anything in the past, publishing with magazines would build up your 'resume', so to speak. Then after that you can seek a traditional publishing system.
2. You can self-publish. Using this method, you would keep virtually all your profits. You could simply print out your stories, bind them together (might cost something depending on what kind of binding, though) and sell them however you want. Either that or you can put them online. This method can also work.
3. Check out a couple traditional publishing companies. You may or may not need an agent. This one ultimately depends on what kind of stories you have written and what kind of publishing company you look at.